# Where in Europe can I find monuments and museums about Napoléon Bonaparte?

Tags: europe, sightseeing, recommendations, museums

I'm interested in history and I want to visit some Napoléon historic places. The most known are  [the Arc de Triomphe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_de_Triomphe) and [The battlefield of Waterloo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Waterloo#The_battlefield_today), where he was defeated. But are there some other places like these in Europe?

Comment: it might be a good start, even though these museums might not be the best: http://www.musees-nationaux-napoleoniens.org/index.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could start your tour in Paris, visiting the grave of Napoleon in [Dôme des Invalides](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invalidendom). Napoleon is buried there since December 1840.

[image]

After that you could visit [Longwood House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longwood_House) on the island Saint Helena. Napoleon has spent his last days there.

[image]

Also worth a visit is [Schönbrunn Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nbrunn_Palace) in Vienna. Not only because Napoleon has spent the time there during the occupation of Vienna, but also because it is a nice palace with a lot of sights. There is a reason why this is a world heritage site ;)

[image]

All images are from Wikipedia.

Comment: St. Helena is an island in the South Atlantic, about 5000 km from Europe and reachable only by ship.  Not exactly a convenient stopover on the way from Paris to Vienna. :)  Maybe you were thinking of [Elba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elba)?

Comment: Yes I'll add Elba to the answer. Nevertheless Saint Helena is Europe.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to argue that Saint Helena is Europe in any meaningful sense. It's a British Overseas Territory, not part of Britain.

Answer (score 5):

The Château de Fontainebleau near Paris is where Napoleon made his palace in favour of Versailles. The palace was extensively modified by Napoleon and is open to visitors.

Answer (score 3):

In Poland there is a small museum in [Witaszyce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witaszyce). You can see there exhibition of items, documents and other things connected with Napoleonic Wars (e.g. they have original Napoleon's hair). They are also organizing excursions to the places in region which are connected with this time.

[Here you can see some pictures](http://www.palacwitaszyce.com.pl/muzea/muzeum-napoleonskie/galeria.html?format=html&lang=en) and [here is main site of museum (no english version)](http://www.palacwitaszyce.com.pl/en/muzea/muzeum-napoleonskie.html).

Answer (score 3):

Think also about the birthplace - Ajaccio, the capital of Corsica island. You can see the house and the museum.

The city is easily served by car/passenger ferries and regular flights from mainland France.
Flights are operated by Air France; sea crossings by SNCM and Corsica Ferries.

The island itself is also worth a few days' visit with its beaches, its mostly mountaineous terrain, winding roads. It is a trekker's paradise with the famous GR 20 trail, the natural reserve and outdoor adventure spots. A small scenic train links the city of Bastia while crossing the entire island through the mountains in 3 hours.